# Will Google search results reflect website text that I replace with a script?

Tags: javascript, html, search-engine, google-search, search-engine-bots

I'm trying to set up web documentation for a project. I want to use variables so that, when the project name inevitably changes, I can just replace it everywhere easily. For example, I want to create HTML pages with content like this:

"Get started with {{project_name}}"

And in the actual user experience, replace it (including in  elements) with the project name so the user sees something more like this:

"Get started with MyProject"

I already know how to do this using JavaScript in the head section, which is obviously only run when the page is opened.

However, and I realise this may be a stupid question, I'm concerned what effect this would have on Google search results for our project. Would our documentation be listed as "{{project_name}} documentation" in results, or as "MyProject documentation"?

If it'll show up as the first (which is obviously no good to me), does anybody know of an alternative method?